# What is the interest, in algebra-of-sets problems, of defining the universal set under consideration as the power set of some set S?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

WARNING : The following question was based on a confusion between (1) the universal set S and (2) P(S) , the set on which the algebra of sets is defined. - I let it undeleted, in case it could help some people who would be victim of the same confusion I fell into.

The definition I misread is :  " Let I be some fixed non empty set that we'll call the universal set. The set P(I) - composed of all the parts of I - can be equipped with two much natural composition laws" ( that is union and intersection).

---

If I am correct, in the exposition of the algebra of sets, *U*, the universal set, is sometimes supposed to be the power set of some indetermined set S.

What is the interest of this definition?

Why is such a requirement?

Comment: Can you give an example of such a scenario where one considers as a “universal set” the power set of something?

Comment: See [Algebra of sets](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebra_of_sets) : "A collection $\mathcal A$ of subsets of some set $X$ which contains the empty set and is closed under the set-theoretic operations..." The power-set $\mathcal P(X)$ for sure satisfies the closure axioms.

Comment: Where have you seen such an exposition? It is not at all a common thing to require on my experience.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza. There is something I do not understand. (1) If  X is the universal teh ( in some context) it means that all sets under consideration are subsets of X. (2) but if  we set P(X) = U , then the sets we will consider will be elements of U , not subsets of U? There must be some gross confusion here I am making, but I cannot clear it up.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. Sometimes the algebra of sets is designated as the " algebra of the parts of a referential set S". It might be outdated.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza. Was the expression " algebra of the parts of a referntial set S" a classical one in the first part of the XXth century? I think it was , but I may be wrong.

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames: That sounds like $S$ is the universal set. $\mathcal P(S)$ is then the _algebra itself_, not one of its elements.

Comment: @mauro-allegranza What about converting your comments to an answer? It seems that the question boils down to a confusion between *universe* and *universal set*.

Comment: @HenningMakholm. You're right. P(S) is the set on which the algebra is defined, The universal set is S itself. My reference was Lentin&Rivaud, Lessons on modern algebra (1964) in which I read ( book 1, chapter 2, § Algebra of the parts of a referential) : " Let I be some fixed non empty set that we'll call the universal set. The set P(I) - composed of all the parts of I - can be equipped with two much natural composition laws" ( that is union and intersection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Algebra of sets](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebra_of_sets) :

> A collection $\mathcal A$ of subsets of some set $X$ which contains the empty set and is closed under the set-theoretic operations...

The power-set $\mathcal P(X)$ for sure satisfies the closure axioms.

As is well-known, we have troubles in set theory with the concept "uiversal set".

Thus, in order to develop at an elementary level the "algebraic" laws of sets, we choose an "ambient" set $X$ and consider it as our provisional "universe". For every subset $A$ of $X$, we have that its complement (in the ambient set $X$), i.e. the set $X \setminus A$, is again a subset of $X$.

All the sets that we produce by way of "algebraic" laws using subsets of $X$ are also subsets of $X$. Thus, they are all elements of $\mathcal P(X)$.

It may be worth noting that (according to the definition above) the power-set "operation" is not part of the "algebraic" operations. This mean that our "provisional universe" $X$ is not a real "universal set" (in the naive sense : a set that contains everything) : it does not contain the set $\mathcal P(X)$.

---

See also P.Halmos, [Naive Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=lgdJDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA7), page 7:

> We have proved, in other words, that *nothing contains everything*, or, more spectacularly,
>
> > *there is no universe*.
>
> "Universe" here is used in the sense of "universe of discourse," meaning, in any particular discussion, a set that contains all the objects that enter into that discussion. In older (pre-axiomatic) approaches to set theory, the existence of a universe was taken for granted, and the argument in the preceding paragraph was known as the Russell paradox.

Comment: It feels like this misses the point if the question was about elementary set algebra in $\mathcal P(X)$. That's not intended to be full set _theory_ -- in particular it doesn't pretend to speak about sets as elements of other sets -- and the universal set is just the set of "all the elements we're considering here".